# Get Google Sheets cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets-api

I want to get the value of a cell in google sheets and be able to compare it to something later. When searching for the answer on the web, I was directed to many different places including the [Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference), and the [Sheets Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/), but could not find the answer anywhere here. I know I have probably missed something, but I am new to this and would appreciate any pointers you could give.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) wherein you can read and write cell values via the [`spreadsheets.values collection`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values).

Then to be able to properly compare cell values, you need to create and update the [conditional formatting](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting) within spreadsheets. I suggest that you also check  [conditional formatting rules](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/conditional-format#conditional_formatting_rules).

Lastly, this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/r-WwOgY--cw) regarding conditional formatting to compare cell contents might also help.